# Multiple inputs on a single line with Twitter Bootstrap and Simple Form 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am using simple_form 2.0 with twitter bootstrap.

I am trying to determine what is the proper wrapper format in order to get something like
[city] [State] [Zip]

I believe my form needs to be

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.input :city,:wrapper => :small, :placeholder => "City", :input_html => { :class=>"span2", :maxlength => 10},:label => false %>
  <%= f.input :region, :wrapper => :small , :placeholder => "Region", :input_html => { :class=>"span1", :maxlength => 5}, :label => false %>
  <%= f.input :postal_code, :wrapper => :small,  :placeholder => "Postal Code",:input_html => { :class=>"span2", :maxlength => 10},:label => false %>
</div>
```

I tried this wrapper

```
  config.wrappers :small, :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls inline-inputs', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label_input
  end
```

I believe I would need to define the CSS as well, but before I go down a rabbit hole I thought I would ask if this is built in somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to have simple_form do this. This places the inputs on one row with a single label:

```
<%= form.input :city, label: 'City/State/Zip', input_html: {class: 'span3'}, wrapper_html: {class: 'controls controls-row'} do %>
  <%= form.input_field :city, class: 'span1' %>
  <%= form.input_field :state, class: 'span1' %>
  <%= form.input_field :zip, class: 'span1' %>
<% end %>
```

The 'span*' classes are optional.

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me in the right direction. I ended up just doing the equivalent of `<%= form.input :city do %>` for the first line since I just needed the city label. The `input_html` didn't seem to actually go into the output, and the wrapper classes didn't seem to matter visually in my case. Probably depends on your version of Bootstrap etc. And I used "input-mini" etc instead of "span1". Just pointing out that it may be possible to simplify.

Answer (score 4):

Using Bootstrap you can add span wrappers.

**config/initializers/simple_form_bootsptrap.rb**

```
config.wrappers :span3, :tag => 'div', :class => 'span3', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label
  b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
    ba.use :input
    ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
    ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
  end
end
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less**

```
@red: #B94A48;

.control-group {
  clear: both;
}

.error .controls .help-inline{
  color: @red;
}

.error .control-label {
  color: @red;
}

.error .controls select{
  border: 1px solid #B94A48;
}
```

**_form.html.rb**

```
<%= f.input :city,        :wrapper =>"span3" %>
<%= f.input :region,      :wrapper =>"span3" %>
<%= f.input :postal_code, :wrapper =>"span3" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the label change the label_input component only to input like this:

```
config.wrappers :small, :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls inline-inputs' do |b|
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :input
end
```

and you don't need to pass `:label => false` anymore.

The `:error_class` is not needed since you is not using the error component

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method, and one that doesn't *require* bootstrap (which I'm assuming provides config.wrappers, since that throws an exception in my project where I'm not using TBS):

```
<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.input :city,        :wrapper_html => { :class => "inline_field_wrapper" }, :placeholder => "City",        :input_html => { :maxlength => 10}, :label => false %>
    <%= f.input :region,      :wrapper_html => { :class => "inline_field_wrapper" }, :placeholder => "Region",      :input_html => { :maxlength => 5},  :label => false %>
    <%= f.input :postal_code, :wrapper_html => { :class => "inline_field_wrapper" }, :placeholder => "Postal Code", :input_html => { :maxlength => 10}, :label => false %>
</div>
```

Then in your css:

```
.inline_field_wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for **horizontal** bootstrap forms:

```
.control-group
  = f.label :password
  .controls.controls-row
    = f.input_field :password, :class => 'span2'
    = f.input_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'span2'
```