# Rails 3 Simple Form with Bootstrap and group of inline inputs

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am using simple form with bootstrap and form-horizontal class. I have some inputs which I would like to group on a single line.

eg.

```
Description     : |____________________________________________________________|
Date/Month/year : |__________________| |__________________| |__________________|
```

I tried the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@example, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :date, :label => "Date/Month/Year", :wrapper => :append do %>
    <%= f.input_field :date %>
    <%= f.input_field :month %>
    <%= f.input_field :year %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But then I get the following error message

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

This triggers on the second `<%= f.input_field %>`

Comment: I tried the top voted answer here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449481/multiple-inputs-on-a-single-line-with-twitter-bootstrap-and-simple-form-2-0?rq=1), but I got error message `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass` on the second input_field in the block.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the tag: `div class="form-inline"`

and then for the date/Month/Year you need to put:

```
<%= f.label :date_variable, "DATE: " %>
<%= f.date_select :date_variable, use_short_month: true %>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I updated my question to provide a better description and your answer will not work. Thanks though